# conditional expectation uniqueness

Tags: probability

Conditional expectation is unique up to a set of probability measure zero, but if $Z=E[X|Y]$ and $Z_2$ almost surely equals $Z$, then is $Z_2=E[X|Y]$ still the case? I think this is false but can't find a counterexample. The expectation condition is still satisfied, but it might not be a function of $Y$.

Comment: Without adding on the complications of conditional expectation, consider whether $X=Y$ a.s. and $X=Z$ a.s. allows you to deduce that $Y=Z$ a.s., that is, whether _almost-sure_ equality is a transitive relationship. If so, then since almost-sure equality is clearly reflexive and symmetric, it should be an equivalence relationship. If not, then almost-sure equality is not an equivalence relationship.

Comment: @DilipSarwate It is an equivalence relationship, but I can't see how it relates to the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the case. Take the counter-example:

Probability space $U[0, 1]$, $\sigma (Y) = \left\{ \left[ 0, \frac{1}{3} \right], \left(
\frac{1}{3}, 1 \right] \right\}, X = \text{id}, Z : x \in \left[ 0,
\frac{1}{3} \right] \mapsto \frac{1}{6}, x \in \left( \frac{1}{3}, 1 \right]
\mapsto \frac{1}{3}, Z_2 : x \in \left[ 0, \frac{1}{3} \right) \mapsto
\frac{1}{6}, x \in \left[ \frac{1}{3}, 1 \right] \mapsto \frac{1}{3}$

$Z = Z_2$ almost surely, but $Z_2$ is not $\sigma(Y)$-measurable.